# how to save contents of a file as single string using java

Tags: java, filereader

I am trying to extract a specific content from text file by using delimiters. This is my code :

```
File file = new File("C:\\Inputfiles\\message.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
String st; 
while ((st=br.readLine()) != null) {
String[] strings = StringUtils.split(st, "------------");
System.out.println(strings);}
```

But as a result, each and everyline is getting splitted by delimiter and saved as array.

Can anyone suggest how I can save the contents from file as a single string, so I can get limited number of lines only as Array.

Comment: Can you share an example of the file and of the string you're trying to extract? It would make the question clearer

Comment: we would like to see how a few lines of the file looks like...

Comment: You're splItting the string and then wondering why the string was split? If you don't want it split, why are you splitting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` to do that.

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Inputfiles\\message.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String st;
    while ((st=br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] strings = StringUtils.split(st, "------------");
        StringBuilder singleString = new StringBuilder();

        for(String s : strings){
            singleString.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println(singleString.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I did using below changes

```
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Inputfiles\\message1.txt")));
                String[] splitted = StringUtils.split(contents, "-------");
                for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
                    System.out.println(splitted[i]);
```